# How to load Image in Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, library

In my recent project, I want to load Image in my Arduino. Is there any library available that can be used for loading Image in Arduino. Give some suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: A small 128x128 gif takes more than 2.5KB, Arduino have 2KB. What you want to do?

Comment: You mean a picture? Sure: convert it to C source code and #include it. Gimp will export in C source format, or there's plenty of websites around that will convert an image for you if you ask Google. However: *what are you trying to achieve? An Arduino isn't good at image processing!*

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a library to load the image to Arduino called as "TFTLibrary".

Loads an image file from the SD card into a named instance of `PImage`. The TFT library has the ability to read .bmp files off the root of a SD card and display them on the screen. Images can be smaller or larger than the screen resolution (160x128), but there is no method on the Arduino for image manipulation. The images should be sized before you put them on the SD card. The TFT library has the ability to read .bmp files off the root of a SD card and display them on the screen. It is possible to load 24 bit bmp image only.

Syntax:

```
screen.loadImage(name);
```

Details available on Arduino website:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/TFTLoadImage